# Proper way to implement radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I am fairly new to jquery, and have a question about how to implement 3 different radio buttons with 3 different ID's. 
I only want to select one radio button at all time, which means, when I click another the other two should be unchecked and the value updated. My code is working, but i'm not sure if it is the proper way to do it. Can anyone tell me, if it can be done in another way?

Thanks!

```js
$("#someID_1").click(function() {
  $("#someID_1").prop("checked", true);
  $("#someID_2").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_3").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_1").val("true");
  $("#someID_2").val("false");
  $("#someID_3").val("false");
});

$("#someID_2").click(function() {
  $("#someID_1").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_2").prop("checked", true);
  $("#someID_3").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_1").val("false");
  $("#someID_2").val("true");
  $("#someID_3").val("false");

});

$("#someID_3").click(function() {
  $("#someID_1").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_2").prop("checked", false);
  $("#someID_3").prop("checked", true);
  $("#someID_1").val("false");
  $("#someID_2").val("false");
  $("#someID_3").val("true");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some_class">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_1" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_1" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_2" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_2" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_3" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_3" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The group is defined as the one with same `name` in the same `<form>`

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with html only. All radios inside one form should have same name-attribute.

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="someUniqueName">foo</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="someUniqueName">bar</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="someUniqueName">foo-bar</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its totally depends on your need if you to use fix radio button e.g. want to use 3 radio then you can use HTML like below :

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</form>
```

else go with javascript / jquery

```
document.getElementById("my_div").innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML +'<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>';
```

above code will add single radio button in my_div

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for Jquery here. If your radios have the same `name`, there will always be only one selected at any one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify your html or you want to do dynamically, you can use `.attr("name", "same_name")`.

```js
$("#someID_1, #someID_2, #someID_3").attr("name", "same_name");

//or :

$(".some_class input[type=radio]").attr("name", "same_name");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some_class">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_1" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_1" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_2" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_2" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="someID_3" style="width:20%"></label>
      <input type="radio" id="someID_3" style="width: auto;">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```